# Hamilton quaternion ring over $\mathbb{Z}$ is a domain

Tags: ring-theory

assuming that $a,b\in H_\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a=a_0+a_1i+a_2j+a_3k$ and $b=b_0+b_1i+b_2j+b_3k$, $a_i ,b_i \in \mathbb{Z}$
I wanna prove that $H_\mathbb{Z}$ is a domain.

my attempt: I first wanted to use the definition of domain and prove that $H_\mathbb{Z}$ is a domain. so if $ab=0$ then I have to show that $a=0$ or $b=0$. if $a=0$ then it is proved. so assuming $a$ is nonzero how do I show that $b$ should be zero?

PS:I want to prove this directly using the definition of domain.
thanks in advance!

Comment: The actual quaternions is well-known to be a division ring, and thus has no zero divisors. A subring can't have zero divisors. You're going to have to look for some other property of division rings to break.

Comment: @Arthur Yes thanks.  since the problem wants me to find $u(H_\mathbb{Z})$ I wanna prove this directly. I want to only use the definition of domain and the division ring.

Comment: Quaternions are normed, so use the norm. :)

Comment: "The Hamilton quaternion ring over $\mathbb Z$": i think these are normally referred to as the [Lipschitz quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the quaternion $2$. It cannot be inverted inside $H_{\Bbb Z}$, because $$2(a_1+a_2i+a_3j+a_4k)$$ must have all coefficients even, and thus it cannot equal $1$.

**Edit: $H_{\Bbb Z}$ has no zero divisors.**

Take two quaternions, and multiply them:
$$
(a_0 + a_1i + a_2j + a_3k)(b_0 + b_1i+b_2j+b_3k)\\
\begin{align}= &a_0b_0 - a_1b_1-a_2b_2-a_3b_3\\
& +i(a_0b_1 + a_1b_0 + a_2b_3 - a_3b_2)\\
& +j(a_0b_2 + a_2b_0 + a_3b_1 - a_1b_3)\\
& +k(a_0b_3+a_3b_0 + a_2b_1 - a_1b_2)
\end{align}
$$
We want to prove that if this is zero, one of the original quaternions must have been zero. This product is zero iff all the four coefficients above are zero. And they are all zero iff the sum of their squares is zero. So we calculate the sum of their squares.
$$
\begin{align}&(a_0b_0 - a_1b_1-a_2b_2-a_3b_3)^2\\
& +(a_0b_1 + a_1b_0 + a_2b_3 - a_3b_2)^2\\
& +(a_0b_2 + a_2b_0 + a_3b_1 - a_1b_3)^2\\
& +(a_0b_3+a_3b_0 + a_2b_3 - a_3b_2)^2
\end{align}
$$
After a bit of checking, we see that all terms of the form $a_i^2b_j^2$ survive, with one term for each possibility for $i$ and $j$. And we see that all the other terms cancel (for instance, $-2a_0b_0a_1b_1$ from the first square cancels against $2a_0b_1a_1b_0$ from the second square).

So what we are left with is that the sum of squares above reduces to
$$
a_0^2b_0^2 + a_0^2b_1^2 + a_0^2b_2^2 + a_0^2b_3^2\\
+a_1^2b_0^2 + a_1^2b_1^2 + a_1^2b_2^2 + a_1^2b_3^2\\
+a_2^2b_0^2 + a_2^2b_1^2 + a_2^2b_2^2 + a_2^2b_3^2\\
+a_3^2b_0^2 + a_3^2b_1^2 + a_3^2b_2^2 + a_3^2b_3^2
$$
But this is equal to $(a_0^2+a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)(b_0^2+b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2)$, which can only be $0$ if one of the original two quaternions is equal to $0$.

Thus, if a product of (integral) quaternions is zero, one of the factors must be zero.

Comment: please check my edit.

Comment: @reijisakamaki You first wanted to prove it isn't a division ring, then when I tell you how to prove it, suddenly what you want to prove is something entirely different? Are you absolutely certain that this time, you are actually asking about exactly what you want to ask about? That you won't change your mind again?

Comment: I'm sorry. Its been only a month since I started studying ring theory. my problem has 4 parts. first part says I need to prove its a domain. 2nd part is saying conclude it's not a division ring. I thought that 2nd part should be followed from 1st. now I do know why this is not a division ring from your comment, tho I wasn't supposed to use subrings. I only wanna show it's a domain.

Comment: When a new asker posts a question asking to prove a false statement, the decent thing to do is to ask for clarification rather than jump to post an answer to a literal interpretation of the question. Not easy if you are bent to rush to answer  I realize. Particularly in the occasions when the counterexample is non-trivial (does not apply here). At least you should be prepared to modify the answer instead of blaming the inexperienced asker.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The question was originally "Prove that $H_{\Bbb Z}$ is not a division ring. I tried this approach, but didn't manage to finish." I see no way my answer was inappropriate at the time. I gave a comment to the original post saying that that approach wouldn't work, then I gave a proof in this answer that it isn't a division ring. Then the question changed.

Comment: @reijisakamaki I have added a proof that $H_{\Bbb Z}$ is a domain.

Comment: Congrats on getting a stnadard calculation accepted as an answer. Hopefully you are proud. How much of the intervening two hours did you use for searching.for on-site proofs that the quaternions form a division ring? Something a high rep-user is expected to do as a model for the new users.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you very much. I know my laziness in this matter has antagonized you over the years. We all have our own standards we would like to hold others to. Maybe I will change some day, maybe not. Time will tell.

Comment: @Arthur Yeah, may be I shouldn't rehash the arguments repeatedly. What annoys me the most is that we have many users who won't show up in meta to discuss what's appropriate. That can be seen as human nature, see [this post by Joonas Ilmavirta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27238/11619), but it ignores [the need for rules](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32316/11619) as I tried to explain as a comment to Joonas' follow-up. It's not unlike some people wanting to play baseball with the full rulebook while others insist on "no balking" and "infield fly" -rules.

Comment: Not having a clear rule leaves the moderators badly placed (as umpires, in the baseball analogy), and everybody else unhappy.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm all for clear rules. I like to tell people not to post full answers in the comments and that you're allowed to answer your own questions. I feel that those are more clear-cut, though, as the comment box and the ask-a-question page literally spells it out. I can see that looking for duplicates might be the right thing to do, but it's really hard to do on mobile, and the only place I've been told to do so are comments from you. And while you have been a moderator, it is still not quite as official as the text hardcoded into this site.

Comment: I understand that to some extent. A) I am only a private citizen, no mistake there (not forgetting that the site is designed to be moderated by the community, which is why I am allowed to do that). B) Finding the duplicates is not easy. C) It is easier if you have answered a similar question yourself, but in those cases I am also reluctant to use the dupehammer (should I have it) because I really want to avoid excessive self-promotion.

Comment: Lately I have been mostly targetting answers to standard questions by high-rep users (such as us both). 1) There is a reason the software lists "Duplicate" as the first reason to close, and veterans cannot pretend not to be aware of that. 2) I simply find it unappetizing to harvest points from banal questions that have been "essentially" handled many times already. I cannot point at a rule saying that a certain type of activity is mostly ok if committed by newbies, and/or only rarely. No such rule exists, but I feel rather strongly about it. That may be a sign of the years I spent here :-/